# Swift MVVM Bind with Boxing

Tags: swift, xcode, mvvm, binding, boxing

I am simply trying to create a weather application with **WeatherViewController** displaying the **tableView** with **cells**, and when the cell is **tapped** leads to **WeatherDetailsViewController**.

I am using the **boxing** way for **binding** and I am confused if I set **Dynamic type** in both the **model** and **viewModel** in the example below. You will know what I mean.

**This is the Boxing Class**

```
    class Dynamic<T>: Decodable where T: Decodable {

    typealias Listener = (T) -> ()
    var listener: Listener?

    var value: T {
        didSet {
            listener?(value)
        }
    }

    func bind(listener: @escaping Listener) {
        self.listener = listener
        self.listener?(self.value)
    }

    init(_ value: T) {
        self.value = value
    }

    private enum CodingKeys: CodingKey {
        case value
    }
}
```

**This is the Weather Model Struct**

```
struct Weather: Decodable {

    let date: Dynamic<Int>
    let description: Dynamic<String>
    let maxTemperature: Dynamic<Double>

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey  {
        case date = "time"
        case description = "summary"
        case maxTemperature = "temperatureMax"
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        date = try Dynamic(container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .date))
        description = try Dynamic(container.decode(String.self, forKey: .description))
        maxTemperature = try Dynamic(container.decode(Double.self, forKey: .maxTemperature))
    }

}
```

**Here is my WeatherListViewModel & WeatherViewModel**

**Inside my WeatherViewModel I have assigned the type to be Dynamic but also in the model in order to bind in my WeatherDetailsViewController, is that right?**

```
class WeatherListViewModel {

    var weatherViewModels: [WeatherViewModel]
    private var sessionProvider: URLSessionProvider

    init(sessionProvider: URLSessionProvider) {
        self.sessionProvider = sessionProvider
        self.weatherViewModels = [WeatherViewModel]()
    }

    func numberOfRows(inSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return weatherViewModels.count
    }

    func modelAt(_ index: Int) -> WeatherViewModel {
        return weatherViewModels[index]
    }

    func didSelect(at indexPath: Int) -> WeatherViewModel {
        return weatherViewModels[indexPath]
    }

}
```

**This is WeatherListViewModel Extension for network fetching where I initialize the WeatherViewModel**

```
func fetchWeatherLocation(withLatitude latitude: CLLocationDegrees, longitude: CLLocationDegrees, completion: @escaping handler) {
    sessionProvider.request(type: WeatherWrapper.self, service: WeatherService.specificLocation, latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude) { [weak self] result in
        switch result {
        case let .success(weatherWrapper):
            let weathers = weatherWrapper.daily.weathers

            self?.weatherViewModels = weathers.map {
                return WeatherViewModel(weather: $0)
            }
            completion()
        case let .failure(error):
            print("Error: \(error)")
        }
    }
}
```

**This is WeatherViewModel**
    struct WeatherViewModel {

```
    private(set) var weather: Weather

    var temperature: Dynamic<Double>
    var date: Dynamic<Int>
    var description: Dynamic<String>

    init(weather: Weather) {
        self.weather = weather
        self.temperature = Dynamic(weather.maxTemperature)
        self.date = Dynamic(weather.date)
        self.description = Dynamic(weather.description)
    }

}
```

**Here is my WeatherDetailsViewController**
**Here I assign the binding to the labels respectively to get the changes**

```
class WeatherDetailsViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet private var imageView: UIImageView!

    @IBOutlet private var cityLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet private var dateLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet private var descriptionLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet private var temperatureLabel: UILabel!

    var viewModel: WeatherViewModel?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        setupVMBinding()
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .never
    }

    private func setupVMBinding() {
        if let viewModel = viewModel {
            viewModel.date.bind {
                self.dateLabel.text = $0.toString()
            }

            viewModel.temperature.bind {
                self.temperatureLabel.text = "\($0)"
            }

            viewModel.description.bind {
                self.descriptionLabel.text = $0.description
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Question is, did I just repeat writing the type Dynamic in both model and viewModel? Is there a better way of doing this or am I on the right track. Sorry for the long code example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you repeat writing Dynamic inside your `Weather` Model.

It does not need to be Dynamic type.

You can create a GenericDataSource

```
class GenericDataSource<T>: NSObject {
    var data: Dynamic<T>?  
}
```

Inside your View Model. This will Reference to your Weather Model without the need for creating dynamic type.

```
class WeatherViewModel {
    var dataSource: GenericDataSource<Weather>?

    ....
}
```

Inside your View Controller

```
class WeatherDetailsViewController {

    var viewModel: WeatherViewModel?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
       viewModel = ViewModel()

       var dataSource = GenericDataSource<Weather>()
       dataSource.data = Dynamic(Weather)

       viewModel.dataSource = dataSource

       setupVMBinding()
    }

    private func setupVMBinding() {
        viewModel?.dataSource?.data?.bind {
            self.dateLabel.text = $0.date
            self.temperatureLabel.text = "\($0.maxTemperature)"
            self.descriptionLabel.text = $0.description
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but may I ask, whats the difference with what I did "viewModel.date.bind" with closure and the one you suggested. I implemented what you said but yea still confused when to use which. Also can you clarify what you mean for Weather Model? Isn't against doing that?

Comment: `viewModel.date.bind` is correct but you have `var date: Dynamic<Int> { return weather.date }`. Which mean you are binding to the property of `weather.date` not `viewModel.date`

Comment: So would it be like this, can you check the WeatherViewModel, I just changed it to what you suggested, and deleted the Dynamic Type in Model as well, but didn't update that.

Comment: did you initialize your `viewModel` anywhere in `WeatherDetailsViewController` class? It doesnt look like you initialize your viewModel

Comment: Well not in **WeatherDetailsViewController**, but my **WeatherListViewModel** when I do **network fetching and map it**. I added that in if that was necessary for clarity. I don't see the reason why I would need to add one in **WeatherDetailsViewController** as it has the property **viewModel: WeatherViewModel?**

Comment: It looks like its working fine for me, but might be a miscommunication? I'm not sure. Binding works as expected when I do **DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter** in **WeatherDetailsViewController** to change, for example, the temperatureLabel after 2 seconds.  From **viewmodel -> to WeatherDetailsViewController**

Comment: ah, I see. You still dont need dynamic type inside your `Weather Model`. You can create a `GenericDataSource` class that will store your `Model` property. I updated the answer. I think that is what you want